# Integer math in c#

Tags: c#, math, casting, rounding

I have a menu of product brands that I want to split over 4 columns.  So if I have 39 brands, then I want the maximum item count for each column to be 10 (with a single gap in the last column.  Here's how I'm calculating the item count for a column (using C#):

```
int ItemCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(BrandCount) / 4m));
```

All that conversion seems really ugly to me.  Is there a better way to do math on integers in C#?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can cast:

```
int ItemCount = (int) Math.Ceiling( (decimal)BrandCount / 4m );
```

Also, because `int`/`decimal` results in a `decimal` you can remove one of the casts:

```
int ItemCount = (int) Math.Ceiling( BrandCount / 4m );
```

Comment: This was what I was about to write. +1.

Comment: It is what I wound up writing. :) +1 as well.

Comment: how's that possible, that the worst possible answer gets the most praise? This is an example how it must not be done.

Comment: @bestsss - why is that the worst answer?

Comment: @David, b/c usually  (not always) using floating point arithmetic to solve an integer issue is bad. But relying on 128 bit floating point (decimal) is just overkill and of course paying the cost to convert it from int -> decimal and back.

Comment: Yes, but the question states he's going this once - I'm sure the cost of data access/file IO is substantially more than the cost of a few conversions.

Answer (score 11):

Why are you even using a decimal?

```
int ItemCount = (BrandCount+3)/4;
```

The `+3` makes sure you round up rather than down:

```
(37+3)/4 == 40/4 == 10
(38+3)/4 == 41/4 == 10
(39+3)/4 == 42/4 == 10
(40+3)/4 == 43/4 == 10
```

In general:

```
public uint DivUp(uint num, uint denom)
{
    return (num + denom - 1) / denom;
}
```

Comment: I like the trick, but I think it's harder to see the purpose of the code.  The answer I accepted is easy to come back and maintain.

Comment: You call *this* a trick? I don't envy you trying to maintain any but the most trivial of programs...

Comment: seriously — ceil(a/b)=((a+b-1)/b) is a "trick" programmers have been using for years before C#.

Answer (score 7):

A longer alternative with Mod.

```
ItemCount = BrandCount / 4;
if (BrandCount%4 > 0) ItemCount++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try something like this ... Assuming `BrandCount` is an integer. You still have the same casts, but it might be clearer:

```
int ItemCount = (int)(Math.Ceiling(BrandCount / 4m));
```

I'm not a huge fan of the `Convert` class, and I avoid it whenever possible. It always seems to make my code illegible.

Comment: I totally agree with you -> Convert.ToInt32(foo) is ugly compared to (int)foo.

Comment: So does the cast do exactly the same thing as the Convert?

Comment: @Ben Mills: In this case, yes (converting numbers). In general, no.